# How to deal with a situation where I end up delegating more tasks than actually doing them myself

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, work-environment

I just gave our team a suggestion about how we can approach a better confidence in the quality of our upcoming release. The team took it very well. I led the initiative, had frequent sync up meetings, coordinated the efforts, answered questions or made sure they got answered, reported the results regularly and did some testing myself. We got good results out of it.

In the whole ordeal, I saw myself only coordinating, delegating, organizing, presenting and unblocking the team and very little did I actually do the ground level work of actually testing. And nobody in the team feels this way except me. Or nobody has even indicated the slightest bit that they feel this way too.

I am a mid level QA in the team, and a new joiner, and I'm not sure, if my behavior (not purposeful) is seen as OK.

How in future must I deal with a situation like this?

Comment: Welcome to the site shehwar. It seems like user52889's answer was helpful to you on StackExchange we often advise you not to accept an answer too quickly. That way, there's more of an incentive for others to offer you their take on your question.

Comment: Congratulations! You're a leader!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How in future must i deal with a situation like this?

**It sounds like everyone's happy with your input, the initiative worked, and there's no problem.**

Nothing you've told us indicates any need to change anything. If you enjoyed it, are good at it and can maintain the team's trust you might want to look into becoming a project manager.

Comment: Thanks. But is it a negative point if i only delegated and hardly did any work? My colleagues may not like it if i keep doing this... I mean my manager appreciated the whole team but gace me special kudos..i feel like im taking credit for what i have only been part of.

Comment: "coordinating, delegating, organizing, presenting and unblocking" **is** work. I love it when I can trust someone else to do all those things and do them well. It means I can focus on what I need to do and don't have to worry about blockers, scope creep and disagreements, or my colleagues being too overworked or confused to pitch in. Sure, if this keeps happening in projects and most or all of your time is coordinating, you should probably talk to your mananger about your job title so that it's recognised that what you contribute is something different.

Comment: Yes. Makes sense. Thanks! But 1 last question, i want to be in a technical role too, not just do project management, i mean i like to have a mix of both. does that mean i still need to talk to my manager for a change in role?

Comment: @shehwar Chatting to your manager about how you would like to be able to contribute in future is _always_ a good idea :)

Comment: Project management can be a technical role, if you;re doing thing like establishing the architecture, prioritizing features, etc.